# Nutrition during rock climbing workouts

Tags: nutrition, muscle-recovery, rock-climbing

I go rock climbing roughly 3 days a week for 2 hours per session. As you can imagine, this exercise really challenges my all around muscular endurance.

How should I be nourishing myself before, during, and after my climbing workouts to maximize the benefits and recovery?

If it helps, in 2 hours, I'll normally climb between 10 - 16 boulder problems, or 8 - 12 ~40 -  50ft routes if I'm on a rope.

Answer (score 2):

You could treat this similar to running and fuel every 40-60 minutes depending on the duration of your climb. 2 hours is the max I would normally running without a Gel or something so you could eat something halfway. You have the advantage of being able to digest a little more normally since your HR will be lower than a runner so you can look at other fuel options (like an Ultra runner would take)

You can also look at Tailwind Nutrition if you simply want a supplement to put into your water bottle.

http://www.tailwindnutrition.com/

This will give you energy as well as hydration throughout your climb